# iOS - Large title hides the top of my body

Tags: ios, swift, navigationcontroller

I've some problems with my navigation bar. Actually, it's a large title and it covers the top of my `ViewController`. I think a video will help you to understand the problem : https://vimeo.com/284493905

Comment: Link is broken. Also, adding links this way isn’t useful in the future because the link may break again and then this question isn’t useful for others. Please add descend pictures to the question directly.

Comment: This should be the link https://vimeo.com/284493905

Comment: Didn't want to downvote, but am. Consider: what about your question (text and link) helps anyone? What actually in detail describes the issue? Why place the need on the *answer* to actually describe *both* what is wrong *and* how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

When you push to your new view controller, scroll to the top like so:

```
yourTableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
```

Or

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
yourTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, the same issue occurs

Comment: You should do the scrolling in `viewDidAppear`